# how to get more information about "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

Tags: tomcat, ssl, alfresco, keytool

I have my SSL keypair and I m tring to use in Alfresco.
I used keytool created a keystore, imported them to it. then in server.xml I changed the keystore and password to my new keystore.

everything looks ok, I can see https without warning or anything. but when I see the stdout log there a tons error of `"unable to find valid certification path to requested target"`

I know there are something wrong with key and the there are many cause of this error. but is there anyway I can track for more information such like "which path tomcat is trying to look for cert?" or "which cert he is looking for?"

thanks

UPDATE: I found that the error came from solr, and search function is not working. seeking further information...

UPDATE2: actually mr  Bruno was right, I added keys to keystore but forgot truststore (was kind of confused how this things work) after imported those certs now the error changed to:

```
org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.LuceneQueryParserException: 09250017 Request failed 401 \/solr\/alfresco\/alfresco
```

Comment: It's certainly trying to connect to something that has a certificate that can't be verified using its trust store.

Comment: Did you try attaching the eclipse debugger and stepping through? That'll show you exactly what certificate and keys are being used, and why the validation fails

Comment: but it's alfresco, how can I attach the eclipse debugger?

Comment: Your second edit seems to indicate that your get an HTTP 401 issue somewhere, which means you've fixed your SSL/TLS problem (unless perhaps some client certificates are not properly configured, but it's unusual to return 401 in this case).

Comment: Start Tomcat with jdpa, load the Alfresco source tree into eclipse, attach the debugger and set breakpoints in key places from the stacktrace. If you're not sure about all that, it might warrant a new question!